# Hero transitions not working properly with layout changes

Tags: ios, swift, hero

In my iOS application use [Hero transition iOS SDK](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) and present view controllers using it.

```
    if cell != nil {
        vc.hero.isEnabled = true
        vc.hero.modalAnimationType = .none
        vc.view.hero.id = cell!.customHeroID
        vc.view.hero.modifiers = [.forceNonFade, .duration(0.70)]
        cell!.firstImageView.hero.modifiers = [.forceNonFade, .duration(0.70)]
    }

    self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

After present view controller if user change the orientation layout changing in the parent view controller. But Hero holds previous layout to manage transition. After complete transition it layout again.

Is there a way to manage this issue?